# rspec 3 raises 'does not implement' only when running full suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec3

Upgrading from rspec 2 to 3. When I run test individually (`rspec spec/models/foo_bar_spec.rb`) it passes. But when I run `rspec spec/models` this test fails:

```
1) FooBar does something
    Failure/Error: allow_any_instance_of(FooBar).to receive(:some_class_method)
      FooBar does not implement #some_class_method
    # ./spec/models/foo_bar_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

indicating the offending lines of the spec are:

```
before(:each) do
  allow_any_instance_of(FooBar).to receive(:some_class_method)
end
```

I then ran `rspec spec/models --format documentation --fail-fast` to see which tests were being run before it; even when I commented them all out so that foo_bar_spec is the first test to run, it still failed the same way.

`--format documentation` proves to me that the FooBar spec is being run first. Running it individually proves the syntax is correct. Is there some hidden gotcha in rspec 3 I am missing? I am already using transactional_fixtures as suggested in a related question.

Comment: do you have other classes with same name `FooBar`?

Comment: nah, there are quite a few test failures from different models' specs. They passed when ran together before upgrading to rspec 3, now only when ran individually